# If Statement for File or directory in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Dont know what I am missing in this simple batch file. I have folders and files in the below mentioned directory.   it never reaches if Exist statement because the below statement is listing out only the files. is there any way to process both the files and directories

Also is there any other better alternatives to find whether the current element is file or directory

Please see me as novice in windows batch programming

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%b IN (D:\Client1\testbat\*) DO (
    IF   exist %%b\* (
       echo %%b --- Directory
    ) else (
       echo %%b --- file
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: If this is to operate over a network then the usual solution will not work.  Just asking if this is for a local drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=u:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b "%targetdir%"') DO (
    IF   exist "%targetdir%\%%b\*" (
       echo %%b --- Directory
    ) else (
       echo %%b --- file
    )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem - you would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

The problem with your code is that your `for` has a target of the **files**, not of *all directory entries*.

The modified code reads a `dir /b` list (directory - basic (names only)). The `delims` is required in case of separators (like spaces) in the names encountered; the quotes to ensure that the names found are processed as one string, regardless of the presence of spaces, and the `%targetstring%\` prefix ensures that the taret directory, not the current directory is referenced.

Setting `targetdir` ensures that only one edit need be made to alter the target directory name.

Comment: Thanks.. Exactly met my requirements

Answer (score 0):

to list files and folders:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b *') DO (
```

Just more info:

to list directories only:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /ad *') DO (
```

to list files only:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d *') DO (
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple FOR loop lists only files.

The simple FOR loop with the /D option lists only directories.

If you want to list both simultaneously, then you must use FOR /F to process the output of a DIR /B command.

```
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "D:\Client1\testbat\*"') do (
  if exist "%%F\" (
    echo Directory: %%F
  ) else (
    echo      File: %%F
  )
)
```

Or you could use FORFILES

```
forfiles /p "D:\Client1\testbat" /m "*" /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE (echo Directory: @path) else echo      File: @path"
```

I tend to avoid FORFILES because it is relatively slow.